# i was getting this error "not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted" when i tried to run the below code

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamodb-mapper

when i tried to run the code using `put` on this entity. i was getting the error as @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted but i can retrieve the data from the databse using `get` and `delete` without any issue, i think the issue is something with the object that i was trying to pass to amazon dynamodb

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "test1")
    class Test1{

    private String prime
    private String lastname

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "prime")
    String getPrime() {
        return prime
    }

    void setPrime(String prime) {
        this.prime = prime
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "lastname")
    String getLastname() {
        return lastname
    }

    void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "Test1 [prime=" + prime + ", lastname=" + lastname +"]"
    }
}
```

and the controller class

```
    Test1 getTest1(@PathVariable("prime") String prime) {
       return Test1Repository.getTest1ByPrime(prime)
    }
```

and the repository class

```
class Test1Repository {

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper


    Test1 save(Test1 test1) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(test1)
        return test1
    }
```

and the error is

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NotSupported.set(StandardModelFactories.java:664) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NotSupported.set(StandardModelFactories.java:650) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:709) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:691) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.convert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:138) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:738) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:640) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.save(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.12.48.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.IDynamoDBMapper$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

Comment: did you figure this out? running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to migrate to [AWS SDK for Java 2.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/#using-the-sdk)